# Finding text between two blocks of selector

Tags: php, dom, curl, simple-html-dom

So, there is my code:

```
<div id="first">
 <div id="third">Lorem</div>
   Lorem Ipsum Dolorez [...]
 <script></script>
  ....

 <div id="second">
  Lorem Ipsum[...]
  <a href=""/>
 </div>
  ....
</div>
```

I need to get `Lorem Ipsum Dolorez [...]` which is between <s>two block of divs</s> one block of `div` and one block of `script`, and `Lorem Ipsum[...]` which is inside div, but without hyperlinks.

I tried to used `simple_html_dom.php`, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Edit: It's a website - I can't change this code.

Comment: Are you trying to get the text with JS or PHP? Is there even a preference?

Comment: PHP-as I said in the last line, `I tried to used simple_html_dom.php'

Comment: Are those id attributes are really there, or just added for clarification?

Comment: Those attributes are really there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select these nodes with the [DOM library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and xpath: (explanation embeded in comments)

```
$html = '
    <div id="first">
 <div id="third">Lorem</div>
    Lorem Ipsum Dolorez [...]
     <script></script>
    this never gets picked up
   <div id="second">
     Lorem Ipsum[...]
       <a href=""></a>
        <span> this span is extraced since its not an anchor element </span>
    </div>
  </div>';

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$first_lorem = $xpath->query('//div[@id="first"]/div[@id="third"]/following-sibling::text()[following::script]');
// first, find the div#first and inside that a div#third ...
// ... and take text node siblings of that div ...
// ... if those siblings have a script node following them (so if there's a <script> after them)

$first_lorem_html = '';
// loop the results and concat the html output
foreach ($first_lorem as $node) {
    $first_lorem_html .= $doc->saveHTML($node);
}
print $first_lorem_html;

// get the every child of div#second except the ones named 'a'
$second_lorem = $xpath->query('//div[@id="second"]/node()[name() != "a"]');
$second_lorem_html = '';
foreach ($second_lorem as $node) {
    $second_lorem_html .= $doc->saveHTML($node);
}
print $second_lorem_html;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You made my day. Thanks for explanation of code, especially first.

Answer (score 0):

Try using strip_tags php function. Example:

```
echo strip_tags('<div id="second">Lorem Ipsum[...]<a href=""/></div>');
```

Returns:

> Lorem Ipsum[...]

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 0):

per the simple_html_dom reference: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

You can do something like this:

```
   $html->find('div[id=third]', 0)->plaintext
```